# Raised spackle discovered mid-painting

Tags: drywall, painting, patching-drywall

I spackled this wall, gave it two coats of primer and the first topcoat of paint.  Now I noticed when the light hit it this morning that I neglected to smooth down this patch of spackle adequately.   It's raised up above the level of the rest of the wall and looks terrible.

Would light sanding before the next coat if paint solve this or make it worse?

Latex paint on sheetrock. The spot is about two inches wide.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It certainly won't get better by itself.

You need to scrape and/or sand it down, and probably spot-prime it and paint it to match what the rest of the wall has had **before** adding a next coat to the whole wall.

There are no shortcuts other than "leave the ugly patch."

File it under "things to remember to check for next time."

Comment: Yes indeed, lesson learned!   I think that LIGHT was the thing that helped me see it.  I did a lot of my work at night on this using regular room lighting but all my sins were exposed when the sun streaked in the next day!

Comment: Paint prep and drywall are where you want strong harsh light directed along the wall/ceiling to show all the defects.

Comment: There's always the tried-and-true "Hang a painting over it" solution...

Comment: Ha!  A great solution if you want a painting hanging six inches above the baseboard...

Comment: Mouse art appreciation society meeting in front of the baseboard! 2:22 A.M. **sharp!**

Answer (score 6):

You should probably wait for the paint to cure but...

- Put an orbital sander on it because doing it by hand will be frustrating as your sandpaper clogs up

  - If you don't own an orbital sander then mesh sandpaper would also suffice
- Once you're satisfied with the depth then put a sanding sponge to it to take care of loose paint scraps
- Give that spot a skim coat
- **Don't forget to sand it this time**
- Apply one coat of primer to that spot and feather the edges
- Apply two coats of color paint to the entire wall

I pray that you're not using semi-gloss on this wall or else this patch in particular will stick out.

I've had good luck with half-inch nap rollers though.

Comment: That is not large enough to require an orbital sander, just use proper drywall sand paper. The kind that looks like mesh so it doesn't get clogged.

Comment: @GlenYates Thanks! I forgot about mesh sandpaper.

Comment: Why "a nice wide skim coat"?  Surely just "sand it smooth", then "paint".  (I think another coat of primer over the whole lot is pointless:  One local spot coat if needed, a coat of local paint, and one coat over the whole lot should be enough with a decent paint.)

Comment: I concur that an orbital sander is overkill. I would also use a higher grit (i.e. 220) paper to minimize gouging during sanding.

Comment: I have used a drywall sanding sponge for this type of thing in the past. Is the possibility of an uneven finish too great to recommend that? Perhaps some other pitfall(s)?

Comment: @Darren "doing it by hand will be frustrating as your sandpaper clogs up"

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That's the point of using a sanding sponge, the [s/pores/channels] allow dust to pass through more easily and it clogs far more slowly than sandpaper. Then if and when it does you can just rinse, wring it out, and wait for it to dry.

Comment: @Darren I think we have different definitions of [sanding sponge](https://static.grainger.com/rp/s/is/image/Grainger/33GN50_AS01?hei=536&wid=536&$adapimg$=)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus While the one you linked doesn't appear to be porous and looks more like sandpaper glued onto a sponge, I have used two different kinds. One had a very porous sanding surface extending a couple mm into the sponge, so dust still built up much slower than with sandpaper. The other actually had channels cut for the dust, these are called "dust channeling" sanding sponges.